# Problem with using power bank for modem with dc dc booster

Tags: dc-dc-converter, modem, powerbanks, router

I want to run a modem that needs 12 volts with a power bank.

I've used a DC-DC booster to increase the voltage of my power bank which is 5 volts up to 12 volts and there is no problem with that.

After I connect the modem and turn it on, it doesn't work. What I have noticed is that after turning the modem on, the voltage drops down to about 5 volts from 12.

I don't know what's wrong.

The booster module I used is XL6009 LM2577:

[image]

Comment: the obvious answer would be the dc/dc booster. You might want to tell us a bit more about that.

Comment: @Kartman sure,  I've added some more information!

Comment: Fix your connections after checking to be sure the booster can supply the required current and surge for the modem. Know the current the modem requires then be sure the power bank can supply at least 3x that current. It comes down to the amount of wattage needed by the modem plus the losses of the booster that the power banko has to supply.

Comment: It looks like the wire connections are intermittent because they have no solder. We do not know how much current the modem uses, maybe it needs more current than the booster produces. Sorry, I did not see the same answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing says that your boost converter module can supply the current your device needs. You'll need to find the datasheet of your module (not just the chip on it), and verify, together with the datasheet of your modem, that it can indeed provide the current.

But also, and **very alarmingly**: Twisting wire around solderpads is a totally insufficient method to connect things electrically. At least one of your connections has a high resistance, and that leads to a voltage drop as soon as any current is draw.

Solder your wires to the board.  What you have will not work reliable, even if your module can indeed theoretically supply enough current.

Comment: additional note: Twisting is an acceptable way to hold the wire in place while you solder it.